# Visual Studio CodeのSFTPで、エックスサーバーへアップロードしているのですが、最上層にアップロードされてしまいます。

Tags: vscode, ftp

sftp.jsonの内容は次のとおりです。

```js
{
"name": "xserver",
"host": "sv10939.xserver.jp",
"protocol": "sftp",
"port": 10022,
"username": "ice888",
"password": "greenmile",
"privateKeyPath": "C:/Users/正人/Documents/ssh/ice888.key",
"passphrase": "greenmile888",
"remotepath": "/home/ice888/siteof.net/public_html",
"uploadOnSave": true
}
```

リモートパスはあっていると思うのですが、階層でいうと、siteof.netの層にアップロードされてしまいます。
public_htmlのそうにアップロードしたいです。

エックスサーバーに電話して聞いても、サーバー上の問題はないそうなので、こちらの問題のようです。

なにかのヒントになるかもしれないので、状況を説明します。
・昨年の12月にsiteofearth.comのドメインを失効してしまい、siteof.netにデータを移している最中です。

・今月にsiteof.netをお名前.comで購入しました。

・Filziraでsiteof.net/public_htmlにアップロードが出来ました。
しかし、vscodeで保存+自動アップロードしながらホームページを作っていきたいので、アップロード確認後に削除しました。

・vscodeで最上層にアップロードしたフォルダは、Filzira上では削除できているのですが、エックスサーバーのファイルマネージャーではフォルダのみ残っています。原因は不明です。

拙い説明で申し訳ありませんが、早くホームページを作りたいので、教えていただけるとありがたいです。

ご回答よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/enh4e0r9ocikta) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エックスサーバーに対する FTP の設定例を紹介している記事を参考にすると、独自ドメインを利用している場合は接続先の直下に `<独自ドメイン名>` のディレクトリがあり、その下に `public_html` などが用意されているようです。

```js
"remotepath": "/<独自ドメイン名>/public_html"
```

あなたの利用している独自ドメイン名が "siteof.net" であるなら、以下のような設定になりそうです。

```js
"remotepath": "/siteof.net/public_html"
```

**参考:**
[エックスサーバー（XSERVER）にファイルアップロードする方法](https://teru1213.com/file-upload/)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。書いていただいたリモートパスでやっても、public_htmlの下にアップロードされなくて悩んでいます。今、試行錯誤中です。